# vendor/database cannot find package in Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm writing a simple app in GO and using postges I have this folder structure

```
  |--- Dockerfile 
  |--- api.go 
  |--- vendor/ 
         database/
            init.go
```

and here is my dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.9

ARG app_env
ENV APP_ENV $app_env

COPY . .
WORKDIR /project

RUN go get ./vendor/database

RUN go get ./
RUN go build

CMD if [ ${APP_ENV} = production ]; \
    then \
    api; \
    else \
    api; \
    fi

EXPOSE 8080
```

when I working docker-compose up I m getting this error:

**Error Message**

```
Step 6/10 : RUN go get ./vendor/database
 ---> Running in 459740ba584c
can't load package: package ./vendor/database: cannot find package "./vendor/database" in:
        /project/vendor/database
Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go get ./vendor/database' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Where am I going wrong with the project structure?

Comment: Is it possible `vendor/database` lives in `/go`, rather than `/project`? Maybe try swapping your `COPY` and `WORKDIR`.

Comment: Can you share your contents of init.go?

Comment: the problem about copy and workdır .I swapped and its worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the source to default directory of the base image with the command `COPY . .`. Then you are making `/project` as working directory with `WORKDIR /project`. So when you run `RUN go get ./vendor/database`, the command is actually run in `/project/vendor/database` which does not exist. Switch the order of COPY and WORKDIR as follows

```
WORKDIR /project
COPY . .
```

Comment: You are right , I switched and it works .Thank you :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your question.